# Add gettext translation keys manually

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gettext

I'm creating a project with the phoenixframework and I use gettext to add some translations. The command `mix gettext.extract --merge` grabs all my translation keys from the controllers and templates and stores it in the `.pot` and `.po` files.

But some translation keys I have in a config file, which I use as select options in a form select box. At the moment I have a list of keys: `[:key1, :key2, key3, ..., keyN]`.

Now I need a keyword list to display the translations and to select the keys with the select box. My result is this: `[{"translation 1": key1}, {"translation 2": key2}, {"translation 3": key3}, ..., {"translation N": keyN}]`.

Problem:

I should not touch my `.pot` files and I can not write my translation keys into my `.po` files, because they will be lost after the run of the command above. The files will be overwritten.

Is there a way to add translations manually so that I can run the command to grab new translations from my project without to lose my manually added translations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a solution and it works with the elixir get text implementation out of the box.

The keyword is: **domain**

At first I created a new pot file with all of my translation keys:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Language: en\n"

msgid "key1"
msgstr ""

msgid "key2"
msgstr ""

# ... and so on ...
```

My file is called `additionals.pot`. Then I run `mix gettext.extract --merge`. Now I have an `additionals.po` file within each language directory, where I add my translations now.

Within my project now I use the `dgettext` method of the Gettext module instead of `gettext`. `dgettext` lets me specify a domain which is the basename of the new `additionals.po` file.

```
Gettext.dgettext(<MyProjectName>.Gettext, "additionals", "key1")
# => "translation 1"
```

That's it and everything works as expected.

[Here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/03/using-gettext-to-internationalize-a-phoenix-application/) is a nice article about Gettext. Search for **Domains** to find another description how `dgettext` is used.